# Referenda function call after passsing

Tags: democracy, origin, preimage, pallet-scheduler, referenda

I want to pass a proposal then have it called once passed after x blocks

I set it up like this:

```
pub struct TracksInfo;
impl pallet_referenda::TracksInfo<Balance, BlockNumber> for TracksInfo {
    type Id = u16;
    type RuntimeOrigin = <RuntimeOrigin as frame_support::traits::OriginTrait>::PalletsOrigin;
    fn tracks() -> &'static [(Self::Id, pallet_referenda::TrackInfo<Balance, BlockNumber>)] {
        static DATA: [(u16, pallet_referenda::TrackInfo<Balance, BlockNumber>); 1] = [(
            0u16,
            pallet_referenda::TrackInfo {
                name: "root",
                max_deciding: 1,
                decision_deposit: 10,
                prepare_period: 4,
                decision_period: 4,
                confirm_period: 2,
                min_enactment_period: 4,
                min_approval: pallet_referenda::Curve::LinearDecreasing {
                    length: Perbill::from_percent(100),
                    floor: Perbill::from_percent(50),
                    ceil: Perbill::from_percent(100),
                },
                min_support: pallet_referenda::Curve::LinearDecreasing {
                    length: Perbill::from_percent(100),
                    floor: Perbill::from_percent(0),
                    ceil: Perbill::from_percent(100),
                },
            },
        )];
        &DATA[..]
    }
    fn track_for(id: &Self::RuntimeOrigin) -> Result<Self::Id, ()> {
        if let Ok(system_origin) = frame_system::RawOrigin::try_from(id.clone()) {
            match system_origin {
                frame_system::RawOrigin::Root => Ok(0),
                _ => Err(()),
            }
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    }
}
pallet_referenda::impl_tracksinfo_get!(TracksInfo, Balance, BlockNumber);

impl pallet_referenda::Config for Runtime {
    type WeightInfo = pallet_referenda::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type Scheduler = Scheduler;
    type Currency = pallet_balances::Pallet<Self>;
    type SubmitOrigin = EnsureSigned<AccountId>;
    type CancelOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type KillOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type Slash = ();
    type Votes = pallet_conviction_voting::VotesOf<Runtime>;
    type Tally = pallet_conviction_voting::TallyOf<Runtime>;
    type SubmissionDeposit = SubmissionDeposit;
    type MaxQueued = ConstU32<100>;
    type UndecidingTimeout = UndecidingTimeout;
    type AlarmInterval = AlarmInterval;
    type Tracks = TracksInfo;
    type Preimages = Preimage;
}
```

After passing, nothing seems to happen.  I tried using the UI and setting it to 100 after delay and at block.  Neither seem to call the function I'm passing as a preimage.

How do we do this?